# Computing the Initial Velocity of an orbiting body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, simulations

I'm working on a simulation program that replicates the movement of planets around a large celestial body (the sun). This is a three dimensional simulation that uses vectors. At present, I'm struggling to work out how to calculate the correct initial velocity vector so that the planet will enter into a stable orbit around the sun.

[image: Diagram of problem]

I've attempted to take the vector cross product of `v1` and `v0` but to no avail. I also attempted to calculate..

$T_0 = v_1 - v_0$

$T_1 = v_0 - v_1$

$NV = T_0 * T_1$

Where `NV` is the new velocity and `*` is the cross product function. This resulted in a *zero vector* because $T_0$ is parallel to $T_1$ so I find myself somewhat stuck. Does anyone know how to compute the correct vector?

Comment: The motion is planar: do you want the plane is the screen and the sun a fixed point on the screen ?

Comment: The sun is fixed at {0,0,0}. I don't know what *"the motion is planar"* means though. Sorry.

Comment: It means that the trajectory is on a plane.

Comment: Okay, and how do I decide/work out that plane?

Comment: **Choose** the initial position and the initial velocity of the planet: the plane of motion contains the (center of the) sun and the initial position of the planet and is parallel to the initial velocity of the planet. One plane !

Comment: Okay but in @eaxdpiotnyeantial answer, he said that the initial velocity vector is dependant upon this plane. So how do I choose the initial velocity before the plane?

Comment: Can you answer to my first comment ? and can you give the context of your work ?

Comment: I've written a simulation using the GLUT Library in C. I am programming the physics entirely from scratch, using vector manipulation. I don't understand what "do you want the plane is the screen" means?

Comment: Since the motion is planar, is a $2$D view enough for you ?

Comment: No, this is a 3 dimensional simulation that can be viewed in three dimensions so a 2D view is not enough.

Comment: Frankly I think it'll be hard.

Comment: If I'm honest, the answer that I've got below looks correct. The only bit I'm stuck on is how to work out which plain that the orbit will run on. There's an infinite amount to choose from so I just need to work out how to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The planet will follow an elliptical path and as an ellipse is a 2D figure it can only be traced to a plane and from two points infinite planes can pass, so you need to decide first which plane you want which is the missing information, because of which you are not able to do so. If finally you form a plane $\vec r.\vec N=p$ then the direction of the velocity vector of the planet is given by $\pm\vec N \times(\vec v_1-\vec v_0)$ the sign depending upon in which sense you want your planet to move clockwise or anti clockwise. On a paralle note the magnitude of velocity should be:
$$\frac{GMm}{|\vec v_1-\vec v_0|^2}=\frac{m|\vec v|^2}{|\vec v_1-\vec v_0|}\implies |\vec v|=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{|\vec v_1-\vec v_0|}}$$
where $G$ is the universal gravitation constant and M and m the mass of sun and the planet respectively.You must play with values so that it looks very real
Great help [here](http://www.solarsystemscope.com/sunaeon/)

Comment: Okay, so the ellipcital path is a 2D figure which can be calculated as Some *plane*, cross multiplied with the difference between the position of the planet and the position of the sun? How do I decide the `plane`?

Comment: @notverygoodatmaths decide how you want a book(a plane) to be placed in air: vertical, horizontal, diagonal, at some particular angle and think whole solar system drew on int

Comment: Sorry, I'm just struggling to visualise it. I'm not very good at this, as my name suggests. Is there a way you could edit your original answer to give me a clearer explanation? This a planet and thus a sphere. How do I decide the vector that describes whether my planet is vertical, horizontal or diagonal?

Comment: I'm rather stuck here and all I need to know is how to determine the plane?

Comment: After some research, I found this answer to be the closest to what I needed. Thank you!